# Codeblock shows blank area when scrolled down

Tags: bug, markdown, code-block, pre

When looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21985736/1) and scrolled down the codeblock I saw this:

[image]

Under the horizontal scroll bar there is a blank area still in the codeblock.
I have never seen this before so I thought it might be a bug?

I just noticed that the question was edited and it is normal again now but I would still like to know if this is a common thing or not.

**Edit:**
I can reproduce this in:
-Google Chrome version  33.0.1750.117 m.
-FireFox 26.0
-Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.16518

OS:
Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide more details. Things like your browser + version and OS + version.

Comment: Looks like a browser bug.

Comment: Most likely you have some rough extension or user script causing this then. Disable them all until you find which of them is causing the problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am not running any extensions or user scripts, I have tested multiple browsers and I can reproduce it in all of them.

Comment: That's really weird then. Just to reassure it's no-repro, I'm using same browser and OS and see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HQQLt.png). Does it happen for you on all code blocks with horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do not see it in every code block, I only see it in the one I mentioned and can only see it in the revision page now. I am   still seeing [this](http://i.imgur.com/uIL8gTx.png?1).

Comment: @Daanvn eureka! Can reproduce now. Need to scroll down to the bottom. Hmm...

Comment: @Oded can you try to reproduce with Chrome [in this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21985736/1)? Scroll the code block to the bottom and see what happens.

Comment: I can see this too in Chrome 32 - only when I scroll to the bottom

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome v33. I guess it caused by `<pre>` on first post [1st post source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21985736/1). after removing `<pre>` in second revision, its no longer visible [2nd revision source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21985736/2).

Comment: OK, not sure it's considered a bug. <pre> tags should not be used for code blocks, hence it's breaking the formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the way the Markdown parser handles code that is *both* indented and wrapped in `<pre>` tags.

Specifically, the source for the [original version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21985736/1) looks like this:

```markdown
<PRE>

SELECT      
        SECU.SECID,     
        SECU.DENOM,     
[...]
    AND SECU.VDATE <= '12/26/2013'      
    AND W1.OBSSCHEDID = T_OBSSCHED.OBSSCHEDID)

</PRE>
```

This really confuses the Markdown parser and causes it to emit totally screwed up HTML with two nested `<pre>` tags:

[image: Screenshot of broken HTML in Chrome developer tools]

You may also notice a bunch of `<p>` tags nested inside the outer `<pre>`, which is also a big no-no.

In fact, trying to [validate the resulting HTML](http://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Frevisions%2F21985736%2F1) reveals that it's even more broken than the Chrome developer tools show, with a whole bunch of mismatched open / close tag pairs:

[image: Screenshot of HTML5 validator results]

The actual HTML code generated by the Markdown parser looks like this:

```html
<p><PRE></p>

<p>SELECT<br>
        SECU.SECID,<br>
        SECU.DENOM,<br>
        SECU.INTPAYRULE,<br>
        SECU.INTENDDATERULE,<br>
        SECU.SCHEDID,<br>
        SECU_CONV.MATURITYIND,<br>
        SECU_CONV.ACCROUTSTIND,<br>
        SECU_CONV.NEWSECID,     </p>

<pre><code>    CASE WHEN W2.OBSENDDATE IS NULL THEN SECU.VDATE ELSE W2.OBSENDDATE END AS STARTDATE,    
    W1.OBSENDDATE AS ENDDATE,   
    T_OBSSCHED.TYPE AS TYPE,    
[...]
AND SECU.VDATE &lt;= '12/26/2013'      
AND W1.OBSSCHEDID = T_OBSSCHED.OBSSCHEDID)
</code></pre>

<p></PRE></p>
```

Basically, it appears that the indented code block is parsed normally, while the literal `<pre>` tags are simply passed straight to the HTML output with no regard for document structure.

IMO, the right way to fix this would be to **turn off all Markdown paragraph / linebreak / list / code block parsing for any content between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags.**  Basically, the only processing done to the literal text between those tags should be to filter out non-whitelisted HTML tags.

Ps. Yes, the SE Markdown parser *should* be able to do this, since it already disables several *other* kinds of Markdown syntax inside `<pre>` tags; for example, the code:

```
<pre>This is *not* in italics, but <i>this</i> is.</pre>
```

produces:

```
This is *not* in italics, but this is.
```

---

**Edit:** It also turns out that, for some reason, the Markdown parser is treating `<pre>` and `<PRE>` differently:

```
<PRE>This should *not* be in italics, but it is.</PRE>
```

produces:

```
This should not be in italics, but it is.
```

Presumably, somewhere in the parser there's a case-sensitive check for `"pre"` that should really be case-insensitive.

However, simply changing the `<PRE>` tags in the linked post to lowercase doesn't fix it — it just makes it break in a different way, with the content being dumped into the output completely unformatted.  Clearly, there's more to this bug than just that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification/explanation!